# how can i enable text shadow in ie

Tags: css

how can i enable text shadow in ie with 1 file convert vars (text-shadow:0 0 10px #fff;)

so make any text shadow work with out add filter or edit all css just

cuz i have about 190 line have text shadow with mix of blur or without blur

any one know how to do that?

i think some one do it with javascript to enable text-shadow element

thanks guys for help me

i test filter:shadow(color=#ffffff,direction=80,strength=12) and others filter but i want make text-shadow in css work in ie like chrome and firefox and opera

Comment: i test behavior:url(PIE.htc); but not work with me :( and he is site have shadow but not work with me :(

Answer (score 0):

Support for text-shadow is very limited, but you may want to try [CSS3PIE](http://css3pie.com/).

Answer (score 0):

To some extent you can use `filter:glow`:

```
filter:glow(color=#ffffff,strength=12)
```

However this is limited to a shadow surrounding the text, no offsetting.

Comment: thx but i want some thing to active text-shadow in css for all elements

Comment: So... you want something that'll force IE to recognise `text-shadow`? I don't think that'll work...

Comment: yeah

in java we can use target for all css element like text-shadow

but how make text-shadow var work and convert some java to make text-shadow work in ie for all ver from ie7

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
http://asamuzak.jp/html/322

Answer (score 0):

Just write this in your **css** file

```
filter: glow(color=black,strength=1);
```

change the **color** and **strength** of your text file ..